# Vmware tools for Windows 2000 and Linux

Tags: vmware-player

I'm using Vmware (vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124 on Vista Home Premium). Where can I download the Vmware tools for Windows 2000 ? vmplayer automatically downloads from the internet but I want to install it on multiple machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked but it doesn't seem as if you can.

Your best bet will be to download a trial of Vmware Workstation (with a similar date - if using old version of player, go for Workstation 6.0~, not sure 7 will work) and expand it, or install inside a VM (On a copy, not your main VM) then take a copy of (or a combination of) the following files:

dar

- win.iso
- freebsd.iso
- linux.iso
- netware.iso
- solaris.iso
- windows.iso
- winPre2k.iso

Then, simply mount and install within player.

Answer (score 0):

File->preferences
in the preferences menu click 'download all components now'
That gets all of the VMware tools iso files.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you could just install the Tools using VM > Install VMware tools if you hate complex stuff.

Comment: [VMware Tools is not bundled with VMware Player and cannot be downloaded separately. It must be downloaded from within VMware Player, as part of the Tools installation process](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1035392)

Answer (score -1):

You'll find instructions for getting the VMWare Tools [here](http://www.hackernotcracker.com/2007-02/obtaining-vmware-tools-for-vmware-player-through-extraction.html) or [here](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/Installing_VMware_Tools_with_VMware_Player.html).